# How do I convert from System.Array to object[] in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, casting, enums

I have a COM function that expects `object[]` as a parameter:

```
foo(object[] values)
```

I want to pass some `enum` fields to it so I use the following:

```
object[] fields = (object[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnumType));
```

However, when I try to pass `fields` to `foo(...)` i.e. [`foo(fields)`] I get an error:

> "Unable to cast object of type `SomeEnumType[]' to type 'system.Object[]'.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the exception says, you can't convert cast a `SomeEnumType[]` to `object[]` - the former is an array where each value is a `SomeEnumType` value; the latter is an array where each element is a reference.

With LINQ you can create a *new* array easily enough:

```
object[] fields = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnumType))
                      .Cast<object>()
                      .ToArray();
```

This will basically box each element (each enum value) to create an `IEnumerable<object>`, then create an array from that. It's similar to Tilak's approach, but I prefer to use `Cast` when I don't actually need a general-purpose projection.

Alternatively:

```
SomeEnumType[] values = (SomeEnumType[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnumType));
object[] fields = Array.ConvertAll(values, x => (object) x);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnumType)).Cast<object>().ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks. i missed cast in between.

Comment: ... and then you just turned it into Jon Skeet's answer, without the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the proper array type. Try something along these lines:

```
object[] fields = (object[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnumType)).Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

The error message is stating that the function is expecting an object array of type "object" and you're passing in one of type "SomeEnumType", so there is a type mismatch.

Comment: Indeed. As Developer is hinting at, Array is an object, not a C++ style [] array.

Comment: True enough - I come from a C++ background: old habits die hard :)