# Best way to make a System.Array into an object[]

Tags: c#, arrays

It's possible to do this:

```
public static object[] untypedToObjectArray(Array arr)
{
    int len = arr.Length;
    object[] res = new object[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        res[i] = arr.GetValue(i);
    return res;
}
```

Is there a better (more performant) way? For value types, every element will need to be boxed obviously which could be slow.

Comment: Wouldn't be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Comment: If it's a how do I do this question rather than a code review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680210/how-do-i-convert-from-system-array-to-object-in-c-sharp

Comment: use `Cast<object>()` and `ToArray()` if you want to use linq

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Slight improve: *reverse* loop into `for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)` since comparison to `0` is faster then to `len`. Another suggestion: if `len` if big enough you may want to use `Parallel.For`

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko -- is that still true in the CLR?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without LINQ :

```
object[] tab = new object[input.Length];
input.CopyTo(tab, 0);
```

With LINQ :

```
object[] tab = input.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Where "input" is your input Array.

Comment: Haha, totally forgot about CopyTo()! Thanks!